# Button click not triggering an event - MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have gone through  previous posts on the same topic but I couldn't figure out what's wrong with my code. Here's my html

```
  @model  Models.Submissions

  @{
  ViewBag.Title = "Application";
  }


 <h2 class="Centre" >@ViewBag.Title</h2> 

  @using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Submissions",FormMethod.Post))
  {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
    <table id="ApplicationTable">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubmissionId)
                </td>
                <td>
                     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SubmissionId)
                </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>                        
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubmissionDate)
               </td>
               <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SubmissionId)
               </td>
            </tr>


    </table>

        <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" /> 
        </p>
     </fieldset>
  }

 <div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
 }
```

Here's my controller. The button click doesn't trigger the http post method of the submissions controller . By the way,  my controller is "SubmissionsController"

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }






    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Submissions submission)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here

            // my logic
            return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks..! Help Appreciated

Comment: Your code looks OK. Are you sure your controller is not being hit? Have you put a breakpoint on the first line to check?

Comment: I think you're wanting `SubmissionDate` in your second textbox.  Can you show the view model?

Comment: `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)` means to display only errors not directly associated with a property (which means you also need to include `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` for each property), otherwise use `@Html.ValidationSummary(false)`

Comment: Thanks  StephenMuecke and Jonesy  for your valuable inputs. The problem was due the @scripts.render part in my code that  was causing client side validation. I have disabled it and and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you're trying to include jquery validation for the form as well, so my humble guess would be, that your client-side validation prevents postback to the server due to a validation error. Try to disable that validation and try again. Can't provide more info, because I don't know what exactly does your javascript do, but I think you should be able to fix it yourself now.

And as Jonesy correctly pointed out, you have a typo in your code. The second textbox should be `model.SubmissionDate`. That is probably causing the validation error I've mentioned earlier.

Comment: I think this along with Stephen's comment should set him straight

Comment: I was able to fix the issue. Thanks a bunch walther.

Comment: @Vikram, no problem. If I was right, you should probably mark my answer as accepted, so that other people see how you fixed it for future reference...

Comment: Apologies ... Done :) new to Stack overflow and MVC too .